# Spring Boot Security - antMatchers, regexMatchers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a REST controller on an endpoint path a trailing slash shall be allowed:

```
/path
/path/
```

This is the default in a Spring Boot.

With Spring Security basic authentication I would like to secure endpoints.

`antMatchers`:

```
.antMatchers("/path", "/path/").hasRole(...)
```

Also with path variable like `{name}` it seems to be easy:

```
.antMatchers("/path/{name}", "/path/{name}/").hasRole(...)
```

Not having to repeat because of the trailing slash I wanted to use instead

`regexMatchers`:

```
.regexMatchers("/path(/){0,1}".hasRole(...)
```

But how to use `regexMatchers` with path variable like for example `{name}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`mvcRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#mvc-requestmatcher) is provided for. For your use-case you would do something like:

```
.mvcMatchers("/path/{name}").hasRole(...)
```

This will enforce security constraints on any path that maps to the controller (i.e. `/path/1`, `/path/1/`, `/path/1.json`, etc).

If necessary, you can then leverage the [path variable in your Web Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#el-access-web-path-variables) using `#name`. The example below exposes a Bean with the name `webSecurity`.

```
@Component
public class WebSecurity {
        public boolean checkName(Authentication authentication, String name) {
                ...
        }
}
```

We can leverage the [bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#el-access-web-beans) and the [path variable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#el-access-web-path-variables) in our web expression. The code passes the `authentication` and the path variable named `name` to the `WebSecurity.checkName(Authentication,String)` method which should return `true` to grant access or `false` to deny access.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .mvcMatchers("/path/{name}").access("@webSecurity.checkName(authentication,#name)")
        ...
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could catch all these

```
/path
/path/
/path{name}
/path{name}/
```

with just:

```
.antMatchers("/path/**").hasRole(...)
```

If you need it more specific try:

```
.regexMatchers("/path(/)?\\w+(/)?").hasRole(...)
```

for paths like

```
/path/something
/path/something/
/path/123
/path/123/
```

that will **not** match for

```
/path/something/else
/path/
```

Comment: But wouldn't "**" map also more sub directories? For example also /path/somedir, /path/somedir/someotherdir, etc. What I don't want, just /path and /path/, or /path/{name} and /path/{name}/

Comment: Yes that's right, /path/** includes all your examples.

Comment: OK, that's why cannot mark as solution. Need to put hasRole(...) on specific paths, like /path and /path/ and /path/{name} and /path/{name}/, nothing else.

Comment: Ok, changed my answer and included some regex, hope that helps

Comment: I'll stick for now with .mvcMatchers(...). Thanks!